# Is it posible to use Salesforce Files with community portal?

Tags: community, attachment, files, file-storage

I need to use salesforce files in the community portal (with the Napili template). Is it possible to display salesforce files in the portal. and is it possible to query the files object?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you mean attachments and documents which you need to access in community portal. If that is the case you can use it. You can also use Articles. It works.
Hope I answered your question.

Comment: You can look at this [page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0&language=en_US)  to see for each license which object or feature is available for community users.